# Looking for examples of tf slim code for training across multiple GPUs

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I'm looking for examples of tf slim code that implement training across multiple GPUs.

Specifically: 
1) How can I split up workloads among multiple GPUs?
2) Is there anything I need to watch out for in terms of variable sharing / scope?
3) Is there anything special I need to do to restore variables from a checkpoint?

I've searched on Stack Overflow and github for examples, but can't seem to find any (just more issues). But my apologies if this has already been answered somewhere - I would appreciate if you pointed me in the right direction.

Thanks all!

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/inception/inception/inception_train.py

Answer (score 0):

tf-slim already contains the code/examples , though it's all over the place and not easy to understand. The basic steps to finetune a model I will outline below:

1. Setup slim by following instructions from the README [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim)
2. Download a pre trained model like inception_v3 and the flowers dataset (script in the dataset folder of slim)
3. Run the train_image_classifier.py script:

   python train_image_classifier.py --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR}
   --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} --dataset_name=flowers --dataset_split=train --model_name=inception_v3 --checkpoint_path=${CHECKPOINT_PATH} --checkpoint_exclude_scopes=InceptionV3/Logits,InceptionV3/AuxLogits --trainable_scopes=InceptionV3/Logits,InceptionV3/AuxLogits --num_clones=2

Here **num_clones** parameter corresponds to the num of GPUs on a single host. To run training across multiple hosts is a little more complicated. I have run this and can see a speedup of almost 2x while training.